# If $E$ has positive outer measure, then $E = A\cup B$, where $A\cap B = \emptyset$ and $A, B$ have positive outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I found this question online while trying to prepare for an Exam, however, I am not sure if my solution is valid. Below is the question and my attempted solution.

---

**Question:** Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $m^*(E) > 0$. Show that $\exists A, B \subset E$ bounded, such that, $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $m^*(A) > 0$ and $m^*(B) > 0$.

(my attempted) **Solution:** Since $E$ has positive outer measure, $\exists A \subset E$ bounded, such that
$m^*(A) > 0$. Let $B = E \setminus A$. Then $B \subset E$, and $m^*(B) = m^*(E \setminus A)$. However, I am not sure if $B$ is bounded and if $m^*(B) > 0$...so this is where I get stuck.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I think you need to be more careful about your choice of $A$.

Comment: @User203940 Possibly, but the way the problem is set up, i.e. $m^*(E) > 0$ and it wanting two bounded sets with positive Outer Measure, it seems like it wants to use the preposition that I used., i.e. there exists a bounded subset of $E$ with positive Outer Measure.

Comment: If $m^*(E) > 0$ are you guaranteed to have an interval in $E$ with positive length? One idea might be to prove this result on intervals and then use something like that.

Comment: @User203940 I would assume that you are not guaranteed to have an interval in $E$ with positive length, since, the proposition only guarantees a set $A$ exists that is bounded and has positive outer measure.

Comment: You are not -- counterexample is a slightly thicker cantor set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I've maybe solved the issues in my head with this problem.

Let $I_k = [k,k+1)$ be an interval. Then the collection $\{I_k\}$ covers $\mathbb{R}$ and we see that

$$ E = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} E \cap I_k, $$

so by subadditivity we see that

$$ 0 < m^*(E) \leq \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} m^*(E \cap I_k),$$

forcing at least one of the $E \cap I_k$ to have positive measure, $m^*(E \cap I_k) > 0$. Moreover, this set is bounded.

What if $m^*(E \cap I_k) \neq m^*(E)$? Then $m^*(E \cap I_k) < m^*(E)$, and if we throw out $E \cap I_k$ from $E$ (i.e. examine $F = E \setminus (E \cap I_k)$) then we have $m^*(F) > 0$, $F \sqcup (E \cap I_k) = E$. (Here we're implicitly using Caratheodory.)

What if $m^*(E \cap I_k) = m^*(E)$? It might be $E \cap I_k \neq E$ still, in which case let $F = E \setminus (E \cap I_k)$ but $\mu^*(F) = 0$. We can now divide up $E \cap I_k$. Since $I_k$ is an interval, we can do the obvious thing of dividing it up into two disjoint intervals so that $$m^*(I_k) = m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B)$$ and $m^*(A), m^*(B) =1/2$. Specifically we can choose them so that $B = I_k \setminus A$. Now

$$0 < m^*(E) = m^*(E \cap I_k) \leq m^*(E \cap A) + m^*(E \cap B).$$

Think about Caratheodory now. Since $A$ a measurable set (an interval) we have

$$ 0 < m^*(E) = m^*(E \cap I_k) = m^*(E \cap I_k \cap A) + m^*(E \cap I_k \cap A^c) = m^*(E \cap A) + m^*(E \cap B).$$

If $m^*(E \cap B) \neq 0$ and $m^*(E \cap A) \neq 0$ then we're done. Otherwise, suppose without loss of generality $m^*(E \cap B) = 0$. Do the same dividing process to $A$ into halves. If, when we keep dividing up our interval, we eventually have one where both of the sets have non-zero measure, we win. Otherwise, we have

$$m^*(E) \leq \frac{1}{2^n} \text{ for all n} \geq 0.$$

But this means that $m^*(E) = 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: This was pretty sloppily written but I can fix it if it's not clear.

Comment: I also realize now that the question in the post is different than the title, but the same argument is correct, you just need to fix some of the choices I made.

Comment: What if $E\subseteq (0,\frac12)$? Then $m^*(E\cap B)=0$.

Comment: Repeat the halving process again on $(0,1/2)$.

Comment: Yes, sure, but it shows that your proof is not general enough yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. "Do the same dividing process to A in halves" means repeat the halving process on the part which has nonzero measure. This is the point of the $m^*(E) \leq 1/2^n$ upper bound.

Comment: Ok, nothing. I didn't read the last paragraph correctly. You're right, it's fine like that.

Comment: You are correct that there are some issues with this proof as is (if we're answering the question in the title, then you need to append your sets of measure zero to one of the sets you find, if we're answering the post itself then the choice of $F$ at the beginning might not be bounded). I'll leave it to the person who posted the question to make the appropriate edits for his question.

Comment: Thank you! In the begging of the post when you were showing $E \cap I_k$ is one of the bounded subsets of $E$, that is actually the proposition I was using. In other words, I just was not being as "barebones" about it.

Comment: @Dalton yeah I just wasn't sure how you would prove it and it was bugging me. If you assume it things might get easier.

Comment: Possibily, I am curious though. You ended up saying that $m^*(F) > 0$, however, I am not exactly understanding how you came to this conclusion? Are you implying that $m^*(F) = m^*(E \setminus (E \cap I_k)) = m^*(E) - m^*(E \cap I_k)$? Cause if that is the case, it needs to be that $E \cap I_k$ is measurable. However, I am not sure how you can conclude that it is of the such.

Comment: $I_k$ is measurable, think about Caratheodory and what F is. Ultimately you can rework it so it doesn't matter though.